# API subdomain - what should be done with the root?

Tags: api, redirect, subdomain, response

Let's say I have a subdomain that I use for my site's API: `http://api.example.com/`

All of the API's methods are accessible as URL segments such as `http://api.example.com/some_method`, so the root itself isn't used for anything.

Should it redirect to `http://example.com/`, redirect to a 404 page [like Twitter](https://api.twitter.com/), emit a basic response in the format of the API with a short message, or just have it send an empty response?

Are there any resources out there (articles, etc.) with any other possible suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's up to you. In a RESTful API, the root would be the starting point for visitors to learn how to operate your system (HATEOAS). But since you talk about `/some-method`, you're probably not using the REST architectural style, so that's not applicable.

I would avoid the empty response. Maybe a short message pointing to documentation for the API? It really depends a lot on how the rest of your system is designed, so it's hard to give "correct" advice.